# I have two sets of data and I need to build a data structure that organizers them into sets. (Python)

Tags: python, set

Using Python 2.7. I have one set of data consisting of id tags:

```
SET1=[{'MISC': u'2759'}, {'MISC': u'2759'}, {'MISC': u'2759'}, {'MISC': u'2758'},{'MISC': u'2758'}, {'MISC': u'1751'}]
```

and another set consisting of different id tags:

```
SET2= [u'15672542c8ed280b', u'1566b77702f8865f', u'1565c2241aebb314', u'155c6888c507e365', u'155c5b8ded9a7c03', u'155c1173f58f1494']
```

As you can see, the sets are one-to-one and each MISC tag relates to the corresponding id in SET2. So for example, the first element in SET1, `{'MISC': u'2759'}` needs to relate to the first element in SET2: `u'15672542c8ed280b'`.

So ideally, I want to build a data structure like so:

```
Matched_IDS=[{2759, 15672542c8ed280b}, {2759, 1566b77702f8865f} , {2759, 1565c2241aebb314}, {...}, {...} ]
```

I attempted this approach so far, but since I used two for loops I iterated over the data twice, and get a very ugly looking set:

```
MSGMatch=[]
    for a in SET1:
        for b in SET2:
            MSGMatch.append({str(a),str(b)})
    print(MSGMatch)
```

Anyone have a more elegant, working solution that they could kindly point me in the right direction towards?

Comment: If they are truly sets, elements don't have any particular ordering, and thus elements between 2 sets can't correspond.  Do you really mean you have 2 *lists*?

Comment: Why don't you just zip?

Comment: Note that in Python set is a data type. It would be better to rename your lists to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @ScottHunter yes, I meant lists, they are both lists as of now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
zip([m['MISC'] for m in SET1], SET2)
```

That should give you what you want I think, assuming your "sets" (they are actually lists) are the same length.

Comment: Yes, my apologies I did mean lists. Sort of new to everything so my terminology isn't the best yet, thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: But you still iterate twice: once for the list comprehension and again for the zip.

Answer (score 4):

In one iteration, you could try:

```
[{a['MISC'], b} for a, b in zip(SET1, SET2)]
```

This will produce the list of sets you specified.

This shows more clearly how to iterate both lists in one iteration:

```
result = []
for i, a in enumerate(SET1):
    result.append({a['MISC'], SET2[i]})
```

Comment: Isn't this still two iterations?  One for the zip and one for the list comprehension?

Comment: In Python 3, zip is a generator. The generator would be consumed while the list comprehension is iterating to form the list. In Python 2, zip produces the list (unless you use itertools.izip or zip from `future_builtins`). In any case, the way you constructed it would cause 2 iterations even in Python 3, because you need to produce the inner list comprehension first, and then zip would be just a generator that you would have to iterate again. See my edited answer that shows more clearly how to do it in only one go.